# Movie about a retired secret agent who is betrayed by assistant

Tags: identify-this-movie

There is an old man who is some sort of ex-spy/agent type.

He is really paranoid and sleeps in his closet with a dummy in his place on his bed. Eventually he gets a home assistant and with her help he learns to relax and stop being so paranoid.

At the very end there is a twist where the assistant was a spy/agent of some sort the whole time and betrays the old man.

I saw it ~15-20 years ago. It may have been a TV movie.

Comment: do you remember anything else about the movie?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could it possibly be [Safe House (1998)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120051/?ref_=nv_sr_3) starring Patrick Stewart and Kimberly Williams-Paisley?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_House_(1998_film)):

> Patrick Stewart stars as Mace Sowell, an ex-DIA (Defense Intelligence
>   Agency) agent who believes his life is in danger from his former boss,
>   Admiral Thomas Michelmore, who is now running for President of the
>   United States.
>
> ...
>
> To complicate the issue, Sowell is in the early stages of Alzheimer's
>   disease and has difficulty in convincing people his information is not
>   paranoia as a result of his condition. Sowell retreats to the safety
>   of his barricaded home, kitted out with a variety of defenses and
>   security devices to try to escape those he thinks are out to harm him.
>
> ...
>
> Mace is initially extremely hostile towards Andi and only agrees to
>   allow her to live and work with him as his daughter threatens to have
>   him committed.
>
> ...
>
> During one such drill Andi mistakes Stu for a genuine burglar and
>   severely injures him with a golf club. Mace's daughter Michelle
>   chooses to call the house at this point to check on her Father and
>   Andi covers for Mace saying that everything is fine, for which he is
>   grateful.

The Wikipedia article is a bit short on the plot, but I think she ends up being a spy and betraying him.